# Redirect to the home page in nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect, digital-ocean, cloudflare

I have the following `nginx` server block.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myapp.io www.myapp.io;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name myapp.io www.myapp.io;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.io/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.io/privkey.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:EC$
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
        proxy_set_header    Accept-Encoding     "";
        proxy_set_header    Proxy               "";
        proxy_pass          https://127.0.0.1:3000;

        # These three lines added as per https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/1942 to remove sock$

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

Now, I would like to do the following redirection:

1. keep the redirection `http://anything` to `https://anything`
2. redirect `https://www.myapp.io` or `http://www.myapp.io` to `https://www.myapp.io/home`

Does anyone know how to amend my server block to achieve this?

**Edit 1:**
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add a `location = /` block to force the root URI to `home`. For example:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name myapp.io www.myapp.io;

    ssl_certificate ...;
    ssl_certificate_key ...;
    ...

    location = / {
        return 301 /home;
    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
        proxy_set_header    Accept-Encoding     "";
        proxy_set_header    Proxy               "";
        proxy_pass          https://127.0.0.1:3000;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

Comment: Where should I put this? I tried to put it in the end of the server block, it did not work...

Comment: You will need to place it in the second server block, anywhere alongside your existing location blocks.

Comment: Have you cleared the browser cache? Tested the `nginx` configuration? And checked the logfiles? You can use curl or your browser's toolbox to confirm that the server is behaving correctly by looking at the response headers (assuming that you are trying the first option).

Comment: I did clean browser cache, checked the syntax of nginx and restarted nginx, there is no error log. When I look at the header (see edit 1 in OP), I don't see it redirects to /home...

Comment: It looks like you have CloudFlare in front of your website, and its cache says the page has not changed.

Comment: Indeed, I have CloudFlare. I just disabled paused it (Web traffic to this website is no longer receiving performance and security benefits. Cloudflare continues to resolve the DNS. You can reactivate Cloudflare for this website at anytime.). At the moment, launching the site does not redirect to `/home`

Comment: Just to be clear, I have updated the answer with how your configuration should look, with the location equals block inserted.

Comment: I put the code in the end, which is quite the same. I just used your order, and refreshed everything, it still does not redirect. And I could notice in the header that the server is now `Server:nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)` rather than `cloudflare-nginx`.

Comment: I don't know what to suggest - it's as if you are editing the wrong server ;-) I just tried the same configuration on my test server (for my own sanity) and it works fine.

Comment: One final observation, your `nginx` version [dates from 2013](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44093371/redirect-to-the-home-page-in-nginx/44094658#44094658) you might consider updating it.

Comment: I just realise that I used `sudo service nginx start` after each modification, I should have used `sudo service nginx restart`... Your answer works... Thank you...